# How to make my countdown timer don't start from the beginning when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, countdown, countdowntimer

I got a countdown code from [this repository](https://github.com/CodingTrain/website/tree/master/CodingChallenges/CC_066_timer) and i made some changes, and i want to make the countdown don't start from the beginning when i refresh the page, my Js code is :

```
var timeleft =5400;

var startTime = 0;
var currentTime = 0;

function convertSeconds(s) {
    var decimal = (s/3600) - Math.floor((s/3600))
    var h = floor(s/3600);
    var min = floor(decimal * 60) ;
    var sec = s % 60;
    return nf(h, 2) + ':' + nf(min, 2) + ':' + nf(sec, 2);
}

function setup() {
    noCanvas();
    startTime = millis();

    var timer = select('#timer');
    timer.html(convertSeconds(timeleft - currentTime));

    var interval = setInterval(timeIt, 1000);

    function timeIt() {
        currentTime = floor((millis() - startTime) / 1000);
        timer.html(convertSeconds(timeleft - currentTime));
        if (currentTime == timeleft) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chrono.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="timer"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using database and set starttime from database and deadline from database

Comment: One way to do it is to set a cookie every time you update your countdown.

Comment: @FarisDewantoro i this it's a bad idea, i the timer will not be correct

Comment: @PoulBak 
I did but i didn't a succeed, this is what i did : pastebin.com/pRXecEUa

Answer (score 1):

You could store the current counter value to local storage (cookie or other options if using html 5) and upon load of the page read it's value and start your timer based on that.

Andrew suggested storing a timestamp every time the interval begins to storage.  Then upon load you get the delta by subtracting the current timestamp by the stored timestamp

Comment: I did but i didn't a succeed, this is what i did : 
https://pastebin.com/pRXecEUa

Comment: It is a straight forward solution.   What isn't working g?

Comment: Store a timestamp of the start of the timer to local storage on page load. Then just do math to get the timer time, rather than doing the 10 second thing ..

Comment: Why not run the code in the onload event.  I think you are executing it too early.

Comment: Good idea Andrew.   That's better